# KAFKA 0.9 new consumer group join and heart beat multi-thread problems

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am try to update my KAFKA client from 0.8.2 to 0.9.0.1 to reduce the pressure to zookeeper cluster. And I'm running into follow questions:

1. The KAFKA consumer protocal say that "The join group request will park at the coordinator until all expected members have sent their own join group request". Then I found that the join group request is triggered by poll() and the method will not return before the group rebalancing finished. So does that means I will need as the same number of consumer thread as the consumer numbers to make sure all the consumers can send out the group join request at the same time? If I have more than 10000 partitions and I want each partition has it's own consumer, does that means I need more than 10000 consumer threads?
2. To trigger the heart beat, I need to call poll(). But if I don't want to get new messages since the old messages is still consuming, could I do that by consumer.pause() -> consumer.poll() -> consumer.resume()?  Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers can read multiple partitions. So in general, a single consumer is sufficient -- it can assign all partitions to itself. However, if you "**want** that each partition has it's own consumer", you will of course need one consumer per partition...

About joining groups: if you have multiple consumers and you are in a rebalance, the rebalance will not block forever. There is a timeout applied. If a consumer does not send a join-request within the timeout, it drops out of the group (for now) and rebalance can finish. If this late consumer gets live again sending a join group request, a new rebalance will get triggered.

Pausing, poll, resume would be the right thing to do. Heads-up: this is going to get changed via [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62:+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) that introduces a heartbeat background thread in the consumer.

Comment: Thanks Matthias for you answer and the heads-up.

Comment: I'm trying to get each partition a consumer because I'm in a environment with high throughput. In my understanding, each consumer has it's limitation of message size for each fetch, so let each partition has it's own consumer should be able to increase the total throughput. Please do let me know if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: Sound reasonable. There should be not problem with having a consumer per partitions. As long as you have enough brokers, the system should be able to serve the load.

Comment: Thank you Matthias.